# Cannot read property 'getOption' of undefined

Tags: jquery

I have the next fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q9htn/72/

It lets an option to swipe `li` to the left.

```
$("#list").on("swipeleft", ">li", function(e){

    var li = $(this);
    var contents = $(li.children()[0]);

    // Slide the item 
    contents.animate({width: 'toggle'}, function(){
        $(this).parent().remove()
    });
});
```

I'm trying the text to be moved to the left when sliding left in mobile.

you can test it on chrome by pressing `F12` key, and then select the mobile icon.

now, it goes right.

In addition, I have the error:

`Cannot read property 'getOption' of undefined`

but it works fine although there is an error.

Can I fix this error? or maybe it happens cause I use beta version?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `right: -1em;` makes the `li` move right if you reduce its width.

Instead of `{width: 'toggle'}`, try:

```
contents.animate({left: -contents.width()}
```

Also, yes it's the beta version that is giving you that error.

Try this **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9htn/73/)**